# Hide popup when annotation tapped on MapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview

I'm creating an iPhone app that shows a large number of pins on a map. I need the app to push another view that will show lots of information for that location, when the pin is tapped.

In my viewDidAppear i have a piece of code that sets the title and subtitle values of the pin just for test purposes.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
            pin.title = @"Some title";
            pin.subtitle = @"Some subtitle";
}
```

in my didSelectAnnotationView delegate i have something along this lines

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPinDetails" sender:self];    
}
```

Now, when i tap on the pin, a popover appears for a brief moment, showing the title and subtitle in a popup, and then the segue pushes the details view. When I tap the back buton to retun me to the map view, the popup is still visible.
How can I somehow completely hide or disable the popup? If i don't set the title and subtitle values the didSelectAnnotationView delegate doesn't get called at all. I will gladly post additional code if you need me to, I just wanted to keep things as simple as I could.

Am I doing this wrong? Should I use some different method to achieve what I need to do? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not setting `canShowCallout`

**canShowCallout** -> A Boolean value indicating whether the annotation view is able to display extra information in a callout bubble.

**Discussion** ->
If the value of this property is YES, a standard callout bubble is shown when the user taps a selected annotation view

For More info you can visit [MKAnnotationView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I was stupid, when adding pins all i needed to do is to set the pin property **canShowCallout**:

```
annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
```